# React-Native android Apk built using expo doesn't run

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm new to react native and I'm trying to build an android app. The app works fine with no errors when I run the development server on my pc and then scan the QR code to open my app in the Expo app. I ran `expo build:android` and when it finished I downloaded and installed the apk on my phone, but it doesn't open. The app stays stuck on the expo splash screen. I've tried installing and running the apk on Nox player (android emulator) but it produced the same results. Below is my `app.json` file.

```
{
  "sdkVersion": "39.0.2",
  "name": "confusion",
  "displayName": "confusion",
  "expo": {
    "name": "confusion",
    "icon": "./components/images/icon.png",
    "slug": "confusion",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "ios": {
      "bundleIdentifier": "net.food.confusion.confusion",
      "buildNumber": "1.0.0"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "net.food.confusion.confusion",
      "versionCode": 1
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "splash": {
      "image": "./components/images/splash.png"
    }
  }
}
```

[image]